# make parent page Blur when dialog window open

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i clicking a Button, i need to show a popup window , pop up window is opening , once opened , i need to do blur the back end page .

My script

```
function showDialogBox() {
    $("#divSample").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        bgiframe: true,
        Height: 500,
        width: 500,

        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        position: 'center',
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        }


    });
    $("#divSample").dialog("open");


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to change the opacity of the parent page - reduce it to, say, 0.3 when the dialog is open, return it to 1 when the dialog is closed.  If you want to prevent clicks on the parent while the dialog is open, add `pointer-events: none` to the show function and `pointer-events:auto` to the hide/close function.

```
function showDialogBox() {
$('#parent_page').css({'opacity': 0.3, 'pointer-events': 'none'})
//rest of function
}

function hideDialogBox() {
$('#parent_page').css({'opacity': 1, 'pointer-events': 'auto'})
//rest of function
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wa3gfxsh/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your HTML

```
 <div style="z-index:99" class="black_overlay1 off" id="black_overlay_loader"></div>
    <div id="loader" class="off" > </div>
```

Add this in script(jquery)

```
function overlay(){
    $("#loader").removeClass("off").addClass("on");
    $("#black_overlay_loader").removeClass("off").addClass("on");
}
```

add this in your class

```
.black_overlay1{position: fixed;_position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;width:100%;height: 100%;background:black;z-index:1001;-moz-opacity:0.3;opacity:.30;filter:alpha(opacity=30);
overflow: hidden}

.off{display:none}
.on{ 
/*empty*/
  }
```

you can get black blur background.. then edit your css to get exact look you needed